# How can I find which data set fit best to a certain distribution graphically?

Tags: distributions, statistical-significance, data-visualization

I am trying to demonstrate how my data respond to benford's law before and after filtering. Benford's law - or first digit law - is an empirical phenomenon, which distributes the probability having 1,2,3,...,9 as first digit in a data set. This phenomenon can be tested with a typical pearson's chi squared test, MAD, or Mantissa's Arc Test. However, the p-values give tricky results in comparison of examining the plots directly. Below there's an example of U.S Balance of Payments (bop), while la8W indicate least asymmetric 8 wavelet from 1st to 4th level.

[image: bop graph]

It is obvious that wavelets really do the job, but how can I evaluate which level fits best and which is the difference between the original and the filtered data.

My first thought is to get the absolute difference between the Benford's distribution and the rest and then calculate the acreage. The one with the less acreage fits best. Is it correct? If not, is there any way?

NOTE: The tests do not do the work because the data are supposed to follow roughly and not strictly this distribution